# Installed ubuntu server by mistake and not can't boot into windows

Tags: 12.04

I am new to Linux and it so far has been a disaster for me.  I installed Ubuntu server instead of desktop.  I installed it onto a hard drive that doesn't have windows installed on it.  Now when I boot the machine up it goes to Ubuntu server and will not allow me to get into windows.  If I remove the hard drive that has the server on it I am able to boot into windows.  The biggest issue is I have a lot of other programs on that hard drive that has Ubuntu.  Is there anyway I can fix this without losing the whole hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Boot-Repair tool from ubuntu? You can install it on a bootable flash drive and repair your boot menu. See details here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I am going to download it now, and will try it.